# what's the downside to leaving ascii files with LF line endings in Windows

Tags: windows, git, cross-platform, crlf

I'm collaborating on a Git project that has developers on OSX, Linux and Windows.  I've set my autocrlf setting to auto which means that it converts the line endings to CRLF as it pulls them down to my Windows system and then should commit them with LF.  However, my IDE (Netbeans) doesn't respect the autocrlf setting and commits them with CRLF still which causes problems for the deployment server and other users.

I'm tempted to just leave the files in LF on my Windows system as that doesn't seem to cause any problems.  I'm wondering what I'm missing that makes it important to convert to CRLF?  My IDE, text editor (UltraEdit), apache and other relevant tools appear to cope with LF just fine.

To summarise, why bother converting to CRLF for windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert to CR/LF only for software that does not understand LF line editings. Virtually all software oriented towards software development will support unix-style line endings natively, the only trouble you'll run in to will be the Windows command line and a few programs that are distributed with Windows.

Comment: Like Notepad. Which you shouldn't be using [anyways](http://www.geany.org/).